# Why the binary division of the two has the same quotent

Tags: arithmetic, binary

I am trying to divide 110000 with 1101 in binary (long division). I use XOR each time. The divisions above should have quotent 100. However I might must misunderstood something. Could please anyone help me with that?

basically I am doing the following

```
     ---011
1101/110000
     0000
     11000
      11010
       1101
       ----
       0111
```

Comment: In the 5th line, you subtracted `1101` from `11000` and got `110`.  That's wrong.  You should get `1011`.  I don't understand what you mean by XOR; you shouldn't be using XOR anywhere.  You should be using the same algorithm you use for long division of decimal numbers, which similarly does not use XOR anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
110000 : 1101 = 11 rem 1001
 1101
-----
 10110
  1101
 -----
  1001
```

Comment: Thank you @Hagen! very nice answer! thanks. However, I am trying basically to solve exersice 20 from chapter 2 from this book sahyadri.edu.in/SMCA/students_guide/3semnotes/network/… . However, the book says that I have to prove that the quotent is 100. Is the book wrong? Or did I understood something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

OP has clarified his question to explain that he is doing long division of polynomials over $\Bbb Z_2$; here `1101` represents $x^3+x^2 +1$ and the coefficients are elements of $\Bbb Z_2$ where $1\oplus1=0$.

```
     ------
1101/110000
```

In ordinary division, $1101>1100$, so we would have to start dividing one place to the right of `1100`.  But
in polynomial long division we have $\deg(1101)\le \deg(1100)$, so
`1101` *does* divide into `1100`, because $$x^3+x^2 = (x^3+x^2+1) \cdot 1 \oplus 1$$ so the quotient is 1 and the remainder is 1:

```
        1
     ------
1101/110000
     1101

        1
     ------
1101/110000
     1101
     ----
        1       (subtract mod 2)
```

Here "subtract mod 2" is the same operation as "XOR". It is also the same as addition mod 2, which I am writing as $\oplus$.

```
        1
     ------
1101/110000
     1101 \
     ----- |  bring down next digit
        10<'
```

Now $\deg(1101) = 3$ but $\deg(10) = 1$, so we cannot divide, and we  bring down the next digit:

```
        10
     ------
1101/110000
     1101  \
     ------ |  bring down next digit
        100<'
```

Again we can't divide because $\deg(1101) > \deg(100)$.

```
        100
     ------
1101/110000
     1101  
     ------ 
        100
```

That was the last digit, so we're done; the quotient (at the top) is `100` and the remainder (at the bottom) is `100`.  Or put in terms of the original polynomials, we should have

$$x^5 + x^4 = (x^3+x^2 + 1)\cdot x^2 \oplus x^2$$

where the first $x^2$ is the quotient and the second $x^2$ is the remainder.

You should check that this equality holds. (It does.) If not, we got the wrong answer.

Comment: Wow!!! very nice answer! thanks. However, I am trying basically to solve exersice 20 from chapter 2 from this book http://www.sahyadri.edu.in/SMCA/students_guide/3semnotes/network/Computer_Networks_Peterson__A_Systems_Approach__Fourth_Edition.pdf . However, the book says that I have to prove that the quotent is 100. Is the book wrong? Or did I understood something wrong?

Comment: You asked wrong! The book is doing *polynomial* long division, not binary long division, and you never mentioned this.  In polynomial long division, `1101` represents the polynomial $x^3+x^2+1$, and the addition is not the regular addition of binary numbers, in which `1101+1101 = 11010`, but the addition of polynomials mod 2, in which `1101+1101 = 0`.  I will try to rewrite my answer to take this into account.

Comment: Thanks. This makes it much more clear for me. Howerver, you mention that "In ordinary division, 1101<1100". Why 1101<1100? Isn't the same with 13<12 ?

Comment: I wrote $<$ when I meant $>$.

Comment: thanks again. I am sorry for interrupting you again. However, I did not understood why you said that deg(1101)≤deg(1100). Isn't both of them 3? That means also that deg(1100)≤deg(1101). In addition why below you made a XOR with 1?

Comment: Yes, both have degree 3, and $3\le 3$ is true.  `1101` divides into `1100`, but it leaves a remainder of `1`.  In general if $\deg(d)\le\deg(n)$ then you can divide $n\div d$, and you get a quotient $q$ and remainder $r$ such that $n = dq\oplus r$ where $\deg(r) < \deg(d)$.  Here we have $d=1101$ and $n=1100$, and we get $q=1$ and $r=1$.

Comment: Thanks again! You have been extremely helpful!